# Find out if a point exists in an irregular shaped ILayer

Tags: arcobjects, point-in-polygon

Assuming I have an layer from a shapefile which is not shaped like a rectangle how would I determine if a point lies within this layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of ways to do it - if you already have both geometries, than you can get an [IRelationalOperator](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IRelationalOperator_Interface/002m0000032z000000/)  from the polygon, and simply execute "Contains" on it.

Failing that, you could execute a spatial query on the feature class (from the shape file), asking for all features that contain the point in question. More [details](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Executing_spatial_queries/000100000240000000/) available than you can shake a stick at from ESRI.